# Using PHP array from Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to programming and I am playing around with htm/ajax/php. I have two text fields, name and animal. You input a name into the name field. If the name exists in the database it returns all the animals associated with that name and does not allow a duplicate animal to be entered into the animal field. I am doing the validation with [LiveValidation](http://livevalidation.com/).

So far I have the name field working fine. It is checking the database and returning a coma separated list of all the animals associated with that name, and inserting them into the results div. However the results div is just for testing. What I want is for the results list to populate the list here:

```
//animal must not include
var animal = new LiveValidation('animal');
animal.add(Validate.Exclusion, { 
    within: [
    // Insert ajax results here
    'cow' , 'pigeon', 'giraffe',
    ] 
} );
```

Here is the rest of my code. I think what I am trying to do is fairly simple I am just not sure how to go about doing it. Thanks to anyone who takes some time to help me out.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" id="animal" name="animal" />
<div class="results"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    //ajax call
    $(function(){

        $('#name').blur(function(){
            var inpval = $('#name').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({name : inpval}),
                url: 'name_taken.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.results').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    //validation from livevalidation.com
    //name must be present
    var name = new LiveValidation('name');
    name.add(Validate.Presence);

    //animal must not include
    var animal = new LiveValidation('animal');
    animal.add(Validate.Exclusion, { 
        within: [
            // How do I insert ajax results here?
            'cow' , 'pigeon', 'giraffe',
        ] 
    } );
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
//name_taken.php
$input_name = trim($_POST['name']);

foreach($names_table as $row){
    $name = $row['name'];

    if($name == $input_name){
        echo $row['animal'] . ',';
    }
}
```

**Table Structure**

```
//$names_table
| 1 | Dave | animal1 |
| 2 | Mark | animal2 |
| 3 | Dave | animal3 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your ajax function you can use `dataType` to set the return data type

```
//animal must not include
var animal = new LiveValidation('animal');
var obj = { 
    within: [
        'cow' , 'pigeon', 'giraffe',
    ] 
};
animal.add(Validate.Exclusion,  obj);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({name : inpval}),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'name_taken.php',
    success: function(data) {
        obj.within = new Array();
        for(var i in data){
            obj.within.push(data[i]);
        }
        animal.add(Validate.Exclusion,  obj);
    }
});
```

then in your php you just need to use `json_encode()` like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Great thanks for the quick reply. I have that working now, it is alerting the values in a popup window. But now how would I populate those values into the validation list?

Comment: does `within` need to be there? moving it outside of the add method, you should be able to just do `animal.push` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Within needs to be there for the LiveValidation to work. I should clarify, I dont need to add to the list. That is just there as an example. I need to replace the list. :)

Comment: I am still not able to populate the `within: []` list from the data the ajax call returns. I must be missing something, but thanks a lot for trying to help!